# XUnit C#- How to test that methods were called inside lambda

Tags: c#, xunit

I've got a SUT and I'm testing a method ApproveTask. Inside ApproveTask I've got this block of code:

```
someService.SomeTask();    
databaseAccess.PerformSafeOperation(() => {
                    databaseAccess.SaveTask(task);
                    databaseAccess.DoSomethingElse(someOtherObject);
                });
```

I mock databaseAccess object using Moq.Mock

```
(new Mock<IDatabaseAccess>())
```

and then pass it to the SUT.
As a part of my test I want to check that the 2 methods passed to PerformSafeOperation were called. However, as I mock databaseAccess, it does nothing, doesn't step into the actual method. How can I make sure that these 2 guys were called?

```
databaseAccess.SaveTask(task);
databaseAccess.DoSomethingElse(someOtherObject);
```

Comment: Alternative approach: Don't mock database access test database access with actual database.

Comment: @Alex Did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: I refactored the code, so that it is now testable :)

Answer (score 0):

The `PerformSafeOperation()` method accepts an `Action`. In your code this is an anonymous method which will be executed somewhere inside `PerformSafeOperation`. However, you are using a mocked version of `PerformSafeOperation` which does not automatically execute any `Action` you pass into it.

For this you need to leverage the `Callback()` functionality in Moq and execute the `Action` yourself:

I don't have your exact code to play with, but I created a simple `IDatabaseAccess` interface, a simple class that takes in this interface which has an `ApproveTask` method which does as you describe. The following XUnit test passes, and as you can see I leverage the `Callback` functionality to actually execute `Action`, and all methods inside the `Action` will then be called.

```
// Arrange
Mock<IDatabaseAccess> dbMock = new Mock<IDatabaseAccess>();

dbMock.Setup(x => x.PerformSafeOperation(It.IsAny<Action>()))
    .Callback<Action>(a => {
        a();
    });

Sut sut = new Sut(dbMock.Object);

// Act
sut.ApproveTask();

// Assert
dbMock.Verify(x => x.PerformSafeOperation(It.IsAny<Action>()), Times.Once);
dbMock.Verify(x => x.SaveTask(It.IsAny<Task>()), Times.Once);
dbMock.Verify(x => x.DoSomethingElse(It.IsAny<object>()), Times.Once);
```